# draw a box, using tikz, given two points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to define a latex macro that takes two points p1, p2 in a tikz picture, and draws a box the diagonal of which is given by p1 -- ({max(hor component of p1, hor component of p2)}, ver component of p2).

I'm not getting the syntax right for the various components of a point. This is what I have:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\HOR}[1]{\pgf@x{#1}}
\newcommand{\VER}[1]{\pgf@y{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\TIKZBOX}[2]{
  \draw (#1) rectangle ({max(\HOR{#1}, \HOR{#2})}, \VER{#2});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to load the package `tkz-euclide`, which is based on TikZ. It had various commands to define a new shape, one of them being the square. I wrapped it in a `\newcommand` so that you don't have to write everything again. You only need to provide the 2 coordinates, it will take care of the rest.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\newcommand\Squarify[3][]{%
    \tkzDefPoint(#2){A} \tkzDefPoint(#3){B}
    \tkzDefSquare(A,B)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[#1](A,B,tkzFirstPointResult,%
    tkzSecondPointResult)
}

\pgfmathsetseed{1234}% ensures same result in output for this example

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \Squarify{0,0}{1,0}% reference without color

    \foreach \colors in {red,blue,yellow,orange,green,violet}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xa}{random(3)+random(2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ya}{random(3)+random(2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xb}{random(3)+random(2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yb}{random(3)+random(2)}
        \Squarify[color=\colors]{\Xa,\Ya}{\Xb,\Yb}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution only using TikZ without loading other packages.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}

\newcommand\Squarify[3][]{%
    \coordinate (A) at (#2);
        \path (#2);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\tempAx}{\tempAy}
    \coordinate (B) at (#3);
        \path (#3);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\tempBx}{\tempBy}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\XCoordA{\tempAx*1pt/1cm}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\YCoordA{\tempAy*1pt/1cm}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\XCoordB{\tempBx*1pt/1cm}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\YCoordB{\tempBy*1pt/1cm}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\XCoordC{\XCoordB-(\YCoordB-\YCoordA)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\YCoordC{\YCoordB+(\XCoordB-\XCoordA)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\XCoordD{\XCoordA-(\YCoordB-\YCoordA)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\YCoordD{\YCoordA+(\XCoordB-\XCoordA)}
    \draw[#1] (A) -- (B) -- 
        (\XCoordC,\YCoordC) coordinate (C) -- 
        (\XCoordD,\YCoordD) coordinate (D) -- cycle;
%   
}

\pgfmathsetseed{1234} % again to ensure same colored squares

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Squarify{0,0}{1,0}
    \foreach \colors in {red,blue,yellow,orange,green,violet}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xa}{random(3)+random(2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ya}{random(3)+random(2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xb}{random(3)+random(2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yb}{random(3)+random(2)}
        \Squarify[color=\colors]{\Xa,\Ya}{\Xb,\Yb}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good for both answers.

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks!